# Ruby on Rails: Trying to create an API that inserts records into table. Unable to accomplish it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, grape-api

I have created a rails app that periodically pings list of urls stored in a Server table. Now I want to create an API so that another application can insert records into the server table using this API. I researched about this topic on the internet to death and could not find a solution. Can someone suggest me how I can use grape gem to create this API? Any relevant blog articles would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) framework is an alternative to the Ruby on Rails framework, not something you add on top. Since you already have a Ruby on Rails app, you can do this more easily by adding this feature to your existing Rails app, which already has the ActiveRecord models and database connection set up.

The simplest way to do it would be to create a controller action `add_url` and make sure there is a route set up to it. Inside the action, run something like this:

```rb
url = params[:url] # get URL from HTTP params sent with the request
Server.create(url: url) # add row containing the URL to the Server table
```

Then tell users of your API to send a `POST` HTTP request to the URL that routes to the `add_url` action, and set the `url` parameter of that request to the URL to add the list.

Even better than having an `add_url` action inside some random controller would be naming the action `create` and putting it within a controller like `ServerController` that handles the creation, showing, updating, and deletion of URLs to visit. This would follow the REST convention of organizing APIs, which is more familiar to API users and which gives you a guiding principle to help you organize. However, if you already have a `create` method inside your `ServerController` that presents a web interface, you will have to make the action more complicated by using Rails’ `respond_to` feature to determine whether you should show a web page or respond to an API call.

Note that the above code has no security features restricting who can add URLs, so depending on your purposes may want to add that feature somehow.

Comment: After creating the feature, I should also restrict creation of record through some sort of authentication. I was thinking of using OmniAuth or doorkeeper. Let me know if there are better way to do this.

Comment: I am also thinking of using rocketpants instead of grape for allowing user to create a record thru an API. Is it a good approach?